# How to prevent div's content exceeding screen view when zooming on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, view, zooming

How can I prevent the content of my webpage (or my div) exceeding screen view on the left and on the right when zooming on mobile? for example take a look at this page that I uploaded:

http://postman-canary-31048.bitballoon.com

I tried to use Div to prevent the content exceeding the page view, it's working very well on a PC (try to zoom in and out from a desktop computer and see how the content stays always in the screen view on left and right sides) but when I try to zoom the page from a mobile (iPhone in my example) then when I'm zooming, the text get out on the screen view on the left and on the right.

How can I prevent this? I want that the only scrolling needed to watch my page will be up & down, I don't want that my content (text, pictures...) will exceed to the sides.

(Please, using HTML and CSS only, without Java Script)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Answer (score 0):

Include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

In the `<head>` of documment

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code, it is over here:

http://fireman-suppression-84203.bitballoon.com

I added the line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

but it didn't help, zoom-in in the iPhone still causing the text to overflow on the left and on the right.

Here is the full code:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <style>
        div {
        width:85%;
        margin: auto;
        border: 3px solid #73AD21;
        }
       </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... Just an example text... 
    </div>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```